# In which Points is the function continous

Tags: analysis, functions, continuity

I have the following function:

$$f(x,y) = \frac{xy^2+x^2y}{x^2+y^2}$$
$for (x,y) \neq 0$
and $0 for (x,y) = 0$

I'd say for $\neq 0$, the function is continous in R because it consists of continous parts (Sum, Product, Division(which can't get division by $0$ since $x^2+y^2$ can't get $0$).

For the part = 0:

$a + b \le 2\sqrt{ab} \to x^2 + y^2 \ge 2 \sqrt{x^2y^2} = 2xy \to \frac{1}{x^2+y^2} \le \frac{1}{2xy}$

When looking at the numerator:

$1. xy^2 + x^2y > 0 \to 0 \le \frac{xy^2+x^2y}{x^2+y^2} \le \frac{y^2+x^2}{2xy}$

$2. xy^2 + x^2y > 0 \to 0 \ge \frac{xy^2+x^2y}{x^2+y^2} \ge \frac{y^2+x^2}{2xy}$

$3. xy^2 + x^2y > 0 \to 0 = \frac{xy^2+x^2y}{x^2+y^2} \le \frac{y^2+x^2}{2xy}$

this I'd do the same for $< 0$ and $= 0$

then looking at the limits the conclusion would be that:

$1. \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{xy^2+x^2y}{x^2+y^2} \ge 0$

$2. \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{xy^2+x^2y}{x^2+y^2} \le 0$

$3. \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{xy^2+x^2y}{x^2+y^2} = 0$

This I'd conclude that

$ 0 \le \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{xy^2+x^2y}{x^2+y^2} \le 0 \to = 0 $

and thus continous in the point $f(0,0)$

Is this correct? As a tip I've gotten that to prove that it is continous at $(0,0)$ to prove that:

$|\frac{xy^2+x^2y}{x^2+y^2}| \le |x| + |y|$

which i don't know how to do..

Another function I have to do the same is:

$$f(x,y) = \frac{xy^2}{(x^2+y)}$$
$for (x,y) \neq 0$
and $0 for (x,y) = 0$

My reasoning for the first part $\neq 0$ would be the same as before.
But I'm not sure about the second part:
It says I should get to the Point $(0,0)$ along the curve $x = ky^2, k\in\Bbb{R}$

I need help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x,y): =|\dfrac{xy(y+x)}{x^2+ y^2}|  = $

$|\dfrac{|xy||(x+y)|}{x^2+y^2} \le$

$\dfrac{1/2(x^2+y^2)|x+y|}{x^2+y^2} =$

$(1/2)|x+y| \le (1/2)( |x|+|y| )\le$

$(1/2)2\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given, choose $\delta =\epsilon$:

$|\sqrt{x^2+y^2}| \lt \delta$  implies

$|f(x,y)| \le \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \lt \delta = \epsilon.$

Used:

1) $x^2+y^2 \ge 2|xy|.$

2)$ |x| =\sqrt{x^2} \le \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, and

similarly for $y.$